# Creating predicted vs observed confidence interval graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, predict, confidence-interval

Hello and thank you for you time and consideration,

I'd like to recreate this graph with ggplot.
The top blue dots are the predicted values from my fitted model `na_lmod` and the lower red values are the observed values from one city's `log_trip` over the years.

Can you please help me combine these three functions ggplot(smooth/point), predict, and some sort of dplyr filter or something?

This code got me the `log_trip` and `year` for the desired city of interest but I'm struggling to even get that to graph.
`filter(transit, msaid == "Denver")[,c("log_trip", "year")]`

[image]

### Desired Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example.  First, I'll generate some data and estimate the model.

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
dat <- expand.grid(city = LETTERS[1:10], 
                   year = 2006:2018)
dat$log_trip <- log(abs(dat$year * .05 + rnorm(nrow(dat), 0, 100)))
dat$year <- as.factor(dat$year)
mod <- lm(log_trip ~ year, data=dat)
```

Next, we need to make some data that will be used to make predictions.  For this model, since `year` is the only variable in it, this hypothetical data only has `year` in it.  If you had other variables in the model, you would need to hold them constant at some (presumably central) value, like the mean.

```r
pred_dat <- data.frame(year = factor(2006:2018))
```

We can then generate predictions with both confidence and prediction intervals:

```r
preds <- predict(mod, newdata=pred_dat, interval="confidence")
preds2 <- predict(mod, newdata=pred_dat, interval="prediction")
preds <- as.data.frame(preds)
```

Next, we put the prediction intervals into the `press` data frame.

```r
preds$lwr_pred <- preds2[,2]
preds$upr_pred <- preds2[,3]
pred_dat <- bind_cols(pred_dat, preds)
```

Next, we join the prediction data and the observed data from one city ("A" in this case).

```r
pred_dat <- left_join(pred_dat, dat %>% filter(city == "A"))
```

For the plot, we need to turn `year` from a factor into numeric, then we can make the plot:

```r
pred_dat  %>% 
  mutate(year = as.numeric(as.character(year))) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(x=year, ymin = lwr_pred, ymax=upr_pred, fill="Prediction"),  alpha=.25) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(x=year, ymin = lwr, ymax=upr, fill="Confidence"),  alpha=.25) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "gray65")) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=year, y=fit, color="Predicted")) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=year, y=log_trip, colour="Observed (City A)")) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("red", "blue")) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=2006:2018) + 
  labs(colour="Points", fill = "Intervals", x="Year", y="Predicted Values") + 
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>